# Specify Button's Background Shape Color Outside of the Background's XML

Tags: android, android-view, android-drawable, android-button, android-shape

I have a `Button` that uses a shape as it's background.

The shape will have different color based on the `state` of the `Button`

Is it possible for me to specify the color of each `state` inside the `Button`'s xml? I am sorry for the newbie question.
Any guide please?

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

How it is currently called

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="@string/login_button_title"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a late answer, but I described what you want in detail in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40197343/6286328), even how to produce ripples in your background, you might want to check it out

Answer (score 0):

Create a color state list in XML.

`res/color/button_bg.xml`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="...">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
</selector>
```

Then your shape drawable can simply use this color resource:

`res/drawable/button_bg.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="..."
    android:shape="rectangle"  >

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/button_bg" />
</shape>
```