# How I will set background of a button on android with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, background

I can not use bitmap as background of a button on android with kotlin

Comment: Check out this -- https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5
Also this post -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235742/specify-buttons-background-shape-color-outside-of-the-backgrounds-xml

Comment: Post your code pls

Answer (score 0):

In Activity:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

When not in Activity:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(Button11.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

For full customized color:

```
Button11.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
```

For setting a bitmap

```
Button11.setBackground(yourBitmapObject)
```

Comment: This doesn't help set a _bitmap_ as the background, as the question asked for.

Comment: Main question is setting a button background in kotlin also for bitmap it will be still same just they have to pass there bitmap in the parameter. Button.setBackground(bitmap)

Comment: Your solution in the comments would be a good addition to your answer, and would make it correct, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you app's layout file. Make sure you are on the `Design` tab. Click the button and look at it's `attributes` on the right-hand side. Then click the **search icon** in the attributes. Type in `background` on the search bar. You will see a background attribute. Click the `Pick a resource` button on the right-hand side of the background attribute(it's on the same line). Select your desired background for your button.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do it _in Kotlin_, as the question asked.